# Why do I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in android studio after adding a 2nd activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

After I decided to create an activity to show the results of the game with try again button. Every 3rd try the game will stop with this error.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3819212 byte allocation with 610080 free bytes and 595KB until OOM

What am I doing wrong here?

My try again button code.

```
 public void tryAgain(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class));
}
```

How I call my result activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SCORE", obstacleManager.getScore());
            Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Are you loading an expensive ressource when showing the result?

Comment: @realUser404 I don't know what you mean by expensive resource. But the result only have a text that says game over, the score, the highest score and a button. No flashy design either.

Comment: If you were loading a few MB animation each time, it would have explained the error you are getting. When is the error showing up anyway? When the result shows or when you click "retry"?

Comment: @realUser404 it happens after I click retry. BTW their is an animation in my game. I animated the background and the player.

Comment: In this case I believe it means you are loading the resources each time you retry the game and never unload them, which causes the error

Comment: @realUser404 Any idea how can I unload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on this 1. calling finish() before the starting new intents in every activity solve this issues.

E.g

```
finish() ;
Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCORE", obstacleManager.getScore());
        Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.startActivity(intent);
```